# web browsing vs. torrent traffic, and bandwidth priority?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bandwidth, process-priority, ktorrent

recently i did download big torrent files. (120 Gb). and i need to seed them back to at least 1.5 ratio. my upload speed is 130 Kb/s max.

the problem is that i need to seed them as fast as possible. but i browse the web a lot. and browsing with no upload left, can be very frustrating.

I'm looking for something like this,

- torrent are on max. seeding rate, but when the browser needs the
  bandwidth, it gets it. priority is to web browser, but when not
  needed, torrent can be at max.
- i'm aware that i can change torrent client max speed. but doing it
  manually everytime and every 5 minutes or so, is hard.

Info:

- i'm using firefox/chrome
- my torrent client is Ktorrent
- i'm on 11.10 with unity
- i do have a router, it's a HAG. and i can't access all it's properties.

is this possible even? 
changing the priority in the system monitor for the applications can do the job?the nice value i mean. 
is there a way to set priority bandwidth usage for different apps?

thank you!

Comment: What you need is traffic shaping. Here is a 'Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO' http://lartc.org/

Comment: it's more than 150 pages. wow. a lot to read, i tried but i didn't understand a thing :) thanks, useful nonetheless. :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: no i didn't find an answer yet. i will edit the question, and if not answered i will delete, as it seems it's not possible to do so. i just need a confirm that's not possible at the moment

Comment: What is your uplink, consumer broadband or something else? Bufferbloat might explain your symptoms, and there is very little you can do to it even with QoS (traffic control) on your end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82410/web-browsing-vs-torrent-traffic-and-bandwidth-priority#comment93157_82410) suggested, you will need [Traffic Shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping). One of the most known program is [Wonder Shaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/). However I would recommend [*Trickle*](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle), because this software is more userfriendly.

Trickle runs in userspace and uses `LD_PRELOAD` to inject some own networking libraries. You can install it using `apt-get install trickle` (or any other tool you like). Normally you would use Trickle like:

```
trickle -d 1234 -u 567 my_software
```

Where `-d` is the download rate (1234 KB/s in the above example), `-u` upload rate (567 KB/s) and `my_software` is any software like Firefox, BitTorrent or else.

In your case it makes more sense to use `trickled` with an own `trickled.conf`. This configuration file should look like the following example:

```
[bittorrent]
Priority = 8
[www]
Priority = 1
```

So WWW has the highest priority, while BitTorrent gets the lowest. So Trickle will make sure, that browsing is always possible. Further details in setting up Trickle are in [`trickled.conf(5)`](http://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/trickled.conf.5.txt) and [`trickled(8)`](http://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/trickled.8.txt).

Comment: thanks a lot! this is what i was looking for. accepted and appreciated.

Comment: @qbi "bittorrent" is an actual/working section? Where are sections documented? Also, does trickled require sudo?

Comment: How to write config file for priority?

Comment: trickle runs entirely in userspace and does not require root privileges. cf. [homepage](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle)

Comment: Just did actually the trick as mentionned above and doesn't work... with firefox and ktorrent with trickeld -vv -N2 before to watch, and tricled.conf as is but doesn't work :-(